# handle Hibernate incorrect connection on Swing app

Tags: hibernate, swing

I got a Swing app that start asking the user for the connection parameters, as every user can make mistakes I want to know the best way to handle when they make a wrong connection attempt i.e wrong url

what I got is a button that sends dbType, user, pass and url to a Map and then I obtain an EntityManagerFactory that last the whole application like this:

`emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit", connectionProperties);`

however is taking almost 1 min in telling me

`java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

- Can I manipulate Hibernate to answer timeout faster?
- Should I change the way I'm using the entityManagerFactory?

EDIT: I have a Connector class that all it does is allow the GUI to send the parameters to it and then allows my DAO to retrieve an instance of that class to obtain the EntityManagerFactory. These are all my connection properties, the GUI changes the dialect based on the DB it picks.:

`connectionProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");               connectionProperties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
connectionProperties.put("hibernate.connection.url", userSettings.get("url", ""));
connectionProperties.put("hibernate.connection.username", userSettings.get("username", ""));
            connectionProperties.put("hibernate.connection.password", userSettings.get("password", ""));`

and this is the method that provides an EntityManager to whoever needs one:

`protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (em == null) {

             em = Connector.getInstance().getEmf().createEntityManager();

             return em;
        } else {
            return em;
        }
    }`

Comment: We'll need to know how your db connections are configured to give any useful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say I'm surprised that it appears the only way to set a JDBC connection timeout is with the static [DriverManager.setLoginTimeout()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#setLoginTimeout%28int%29). I expected to find some timeout support in the popular connection pools, but it seems not to exist except in C3P0's [non-pooling DataSource implementation](http://www.outsourcecafe.com/javagen-agile/xref/org/javagen/agile/db/util/DriverManagerDataSource.html#269), which you wouldn't want to use for a production app.

Comment: there is another question that suggest what you just said and it seems its the only way... and is a bit different for OracleDriver, thx